# If/else for voice option settings

Tags: javascript

I am trying to alternate some config options depending on whether 'text' or 'ssml' is used

Do I need to do an exact match of the text or use a `!=` to always ensure an exact match?

```
if textOption = "text" {
    const request = {
        input: { text: mytextvariable },
    }
    else {
        const request = {
            input: { ssml: mytextvariable },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if` statement needs brackets, and you need to use `==` or `===` for equality check `=` is assignment. In addition if you declare the `const` inside the `if` or `else` body, you won't be able to use it outside.

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis and double/tripple equal signs for comapring the value.

```
if (textOption === "text") {
```

A shorte approach is to take a conditional operator with the check and the alternatives.

```js
var textOption = 'text',
    mytextvariable = 'foo',
    request = {
        input: textOption === "text"
            ? { text: mytextvariable }
            : { ssml: mytextvariable }
    };

console.log(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above statement will always execute `if` since you have used `=` instead of `==` or `===`

```
let request; // the scope should be outside the blocks
if(textOption == "text") {
    request = {
        input: { text: mytextvariable },
    }
} else {
    request = {
        input: { ssml: mytextvariable },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this:

```
    const request = textOption === "text" ? { input: { text: mytextvariable }} : { input: { ssml: mytextvariable } };
```

Ternary operator improves readability

Answer (score 0):

```
var textOption = 'text',
    mytextvariable = 'foo',
    request = {
        input: { [textOption]: mytextvariable }
    };
```

This way property name is based on `textOption` variable value.

If your variable can have multiple values (not only text and ssml) you can use expression instead

```
request = {
    input: { [textOption === 'text' ? 'text' : 'ssml']: mytextvariable }
};
```